# How do I replace characters in a Google Datastore query result object?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, inheritance, scope, jinja2

I'm new to Python, Google AppEngine and Jinja. If I've posted too much code below, I am sorry. This is my first posted question to StackOverflow.

I'm building a blog (for a class) and I need to replace newline characters "\n" in the user's post. The function that queries the database sends it's results to a render() function.

All the code works perfectly until I add the line of code that is supposed to replace the "\n."

I've done a variety of edits and I just can't deduce what the AppEngine, or Jinja, or Python wants me to do to satisfy it.

**My database class** sets up the db_blog Kind with four types, including '**post_content**'

```
class db_blog(db.Model):
    post_subject = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    post_content = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    post_created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    post_last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

**The 'Newpost' class** I want this to receive the '**query_select**' object from the **Blog** class below.

```
class Newpost(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.response.out.write(*args, **kwds)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kwds):
        self._render_text = self.post_content.replace("\n", "<br />") ##<-- See here 
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kwds))
```

**The Blog class** gets all user posts and sends them to 'Newpost' to be rendered.

```
class Blog(Newpost):
    def get(self):
        query_select = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM db_blog ORDER BY post_created DESC")
        self.render('blog_posts.htm', query_select = query_select)
```

## 1. **As shown above, the code will generate this error:**

AttributeError: 'Blog' object has no attribute 'post_content'

I take it that class **Blog** needs to inherit from **db_blog**, so (See #2)

## 2. If I add **db_blog** to the **Blog** class' parameter list I get a new error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

I think the error is telling me that I'm passing an object that doesn't exist, so I'm really confused. If I comment-out the line trying to replace the "\n"character, this code runs perfectly - so how can it NOT be passing the object? Or claim it's == None?

More importantly, how can I get it to work!

Much thanks to you who read this far, and kingdoms of wealth to s/he that can get me going.

Comment: try replacing "\n" with "\\n."
If the way you're receiving the information includes the text "\n" and not just a new line, then you need to represent that as such. "\n" in python is a string containing simply a new line, whereas "\\n" cancels out the backslash and so actually contains the text "slash n".

Comment: As an aside, you would be well-served to change your model name to use CamelCase ("DB_Blog" or a more descriptive "BlogPost"), which is more Pythonic (and makes it clear that it's a class, not a function/object). You might also consider changing the name of `query_select` to something more descriptive (e.g. `posts` or `post_query` or something like that), which would make it easier for you and others to understand your code.

Comment: Thank you both for the responses. The naming of objects(sic) is important to me, and it's hard to do until one has a global understanding of each object in the code. Pin the tail on the whirlwind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the attribute error is because the `self` in `Newpost.get` refers to the `RequestHandler` (`Blog`) and *not* to the post that you want.  I suggest that, instead of defining the conversion in your view function, added it as a property on the model, e.g.

```
class db_blog(db.Model):

    post_subject = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    post_content = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    post_created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    post_last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

    @property
    def escaped_content(self):
        # possibly want to escape HTML in your post_content first
        return self.post_content.replace("\n", "<br />")
```

Then, you can just pass along `query_select` to your template (as you are currently doing now):

```
{% for post in query_select %}
{{ post.escaped_content | safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

You need to use safe above, because otherwise jinja will escape your `<br />`. Since I can't see you template, I don't know if this exactly fits what you are doing, but hopefully you get the point.

To explain the three lines of jinja above:

1. `{% for post in query_select %}` - just like a for loop, iterates over the posts, and each post should be a `db_blog` instance (from your query).
2. `post.escaped_content` is exactly equivalent to calling the `escaped_content` attribute of your db_blog model in Python.
3. `{{ post.escaped_content | safe }}` applies the `safe` filter to the string produced by escaped content (without `safe`, jinja  would convert `<br />` to `&lt;br /&gt;` (which would literally display `<br />` on the page).
4. `{% endfor %}` ends the for loop.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I want to express atomic control over each value".  This assumes that you've passed a list of items called "query_select" and that each one is an instance of your `db_blog` model.  What happens if you just hardcode it (e.g. just pass `db_blog.all()` as `query_select`, just so you are sure that you are actually getting `db_blog` instances.

Comment: Awesome. I had to tinker only 20 minutes (not that swift yet) to atomize the values out of the rows, but it works, and it works as I wanted it. Danke, Domo, Gracias, Merci, Thanks!!!

Comment: @user1473511 I'm glad that it worked out.  If you found the answer helpful, you can click the checkmark on under the up/down arrows on this answer to accept it. This tells others that your question was actually resolved. (also it's nice to upvote answers that were helpful, regardless of whether you accept them ;) )

Comment: I'm new, so my code is likely verbose. I have multiple columns in the query_select 'object'(sic), and I needed to put each value in a different HTML container. I modified the HTML template file, and the function you showed me. `<div class="subject" name="subject">{{p.escaped_content[0] | safe}}</div>
      <div class="content" name="content">{{p.escaped_content[1] | safe}}</div>`                                         `@property
    def escaped_content(self):
        ps = self.post_subject.replace("\n", "<br />") 
        pc = self.post_content.replace("\n", "<br />") 
        return ps, pc`

Comment: Also, I can't yet Vote Up your comment because my reputation is only 11. Once I get to 15 I can vote. I SURELY am grateful, and I will come back when my Reputation is higher, and maybe I will still be able to Vote it Up. This saved me a lot of time, I really wanted to move on to the final Unit of my class. THANK YOU!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing this, @JeffTratner made a great suggestion for making the replacement a property of your model. I definitely support that as a good solution, so hopefully this will just help you understand what is going on :)

---

Welcome! I'll preface this by saying I haven't used jinja (nor am any sort of GAE expert), so I'll try to focus on what I believe is causing your problem (and other far smarter people will correct me quickly).

**The Error**

When you use Gql to query your datastore, the result is an iterable. 
In your code, `query_select` is one of those iterables, each item of which is a `db_blog` entity with the four properties you specified. (Note: you could probably change `db_blog` to `Blog` [style conventions, etc.], and I'm going to suggest getting rid of that class later anyway :))

It looks like what you're trying to do is replace any newline characters with `<br>`'s, and to do so you are calling the `replace` method on `self.post_content`. The problem with this is that `self` is this context is a `Blog` instance, which is completely different from
what you actually want (which would be the items inside of `query_select`). **EDIT:** JeffTratner's method is better than what I had previously, so I am removing what I had and will assume that you set up your model as he suggested :) That being the case, you can simply run your query and then pass the results to the template:

```
query_select = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM db_blog ORDER BY post_created DESC")
self.write(self.render_str(template, **kwds))
```

The key takeaway - querying the datastore will [almost] always return an iterable. Therefore if you want to do additional things with the returned data, you will have to iterate over your results:

```
query_select = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM db_blog ORDER BY post_created DESC")
for result in query_select:
    # Do stuff...
```

**The Structure**

Take this with a grain of salt as I'm not sure what your intentions are, but is there a reason that `Blog` is its own class? 
I don't see a `get` method in Newpost - is that ever accessed directly? If not, could you achieve the same functionality by removing `Blog` completely and moving the `get` method into `Newpost`?

```
class Newpost(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        query_select = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM db_blog ORDER BY post_created DESC")
        self.render('blog_posts.htm', query_select = query_select)

    def write(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.response.out.write(*args, **kwds)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kwds):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kwds))
```

This structure would mean that all `get` calls to `Newpost` would query the datastore and render the results (without needing a separate class). Also, this may be because I'm not familiar with jinja, but it seems like you could probably condense the `render`/`render_str`/`write` methods into one, but I guess that can wait since it is working now :) ). In case you want to try, here is a completely untested (and very likely wrong), way of possibly doing it:

```
class Newpost(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        query_select = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM db_blog ORDER BY post_created DESC")
        self.render('blog_posts.htm', query_select = query_select)

    def render(self, template, **kwds):        
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        self.response.out.write(t.render(**kwds))
```

Sorry for the wall of text - hopefully something is useful in there!

Comment: Thank you BOTH for your answers. at:Rocket Donkey, the "wall of text" was exceptionally helpful. I'm very attached to terminology and having things spelled out helps a great deal in confirm the logic. at:Jeff Tratner, I think I grok it. Thank you champions!!!

Comment: @user1473511 No prob! I removed my suggestion for doing the replace as Jeff's is better all around (and my original would have required a few more steps to get it to work properly). Good luck with everything.